# after I boot my USB stick with ubuntu 12.04 on and click install on hard disk the installer freezes

Tags: system-installation

as soon as it loads the languages list it freezes, I can still move my mouse but cant click anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the minimal installation image from the community help wiki. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD